# Jquery on() prevent default dosent work

Tags: javascript, jquery

Im using

```
$('#c_itinerarios').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#visordetallado").empty();
    var url = $(this).attr('href');
    $("#visorgeneral").load(url);
});
```

Works perfect but I'm trying to move to the `on()` handler like this

```
$('#c_itinerarios').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#visordetallado").empty();
    var url = $(this).attr('href');
    $("#visorgeneral").load(url);
});
```

but now the `preventDefault` is not doing its job.

Comment: What version of jQuery are you using? Is the rest of the code in the new handler executing? Because the modification shouldn't make a difference; they're basically equivalent

Comment: Seems working to me on jQuery 1.9, 1.10: http://jsfiddle.net/cfuDP/

Comment: Internally `.click()` method is just a shortcut over `.on('click'`, so it's highly unlikely that what you've described is truth

Comment: does `.bind('click', function() { ... })` work in your example?

Comment: Is preventDefault() is the only thing not working or the entire thing is not working.. ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$( '#c_itinerarios' ).click( function( e ) {

    $( "#visordetallado" ).empty();

    var url = $(this).attr( 'href' );

    $( "#visorgeneral" ).load(url);

    return false;

});`